# Calling function template specialization using C calling conventions

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template

```
template<typename T> void f(T t) { }
```

And I want to pass the address of a specific specialization of it to a C function

```
g(&f<int>);
```

But as I want to be portable, I want the calling convention of "f" to match the one of C. So I experimented how language linkage affects calling convention and found

- The language linkage of the *function type* affects calling convention to use
- The language linkage of the *function name* affects mangling

The language linkage section of the C++ spec says

> In a linkage-specification, the speciﬁed language linkage applies to the function types of all function declarators, function names with external linkage, and variable names with external linkage declared within the linkage-specification.

So to prevent disabling of mangling, which is needed for templates to distinguish different specializations from each other in the object file, I went as follows

```
extern "C" {
    /* function name will not be affected */
    template<typename T> static void f(T t) { }
}
```

But it gives me a compiler error saying that templates cannot have C language linkage, which I take it to mean that it complains about the function template's function type. And in fact, I found the spec to say

> A template, a template explicit specialization (14.7.3), and a class template partial specialization shall not have C linkage

Now it's obvious to me that we don't want to change the *name*'s linkage, because we rely on mangling to work. But what is the reason for forbidding to change the *type*'s linkage? It seems to restrict us to having to use C++ calling convention; does someone know the reason, and whether there is an easy work around to achieve my initial goal?

---

I changed the way I try to give linkage to only the type now, as follows

```
extern "C" typedef void ftype(int);

template<typename T>
ftype f;
```

And this works fine. Sadly, I don't see a way to define `f` when using this technique. But anyway, no compiler I tried diagnoses this (tried EDG/comeau, GCC and clang), even though this looks like exactly the same situation as before: The name should have no C language linkage, but only the type has.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the C header look like? Somewhere, the C source must enumerate the callback types allowed. You should take that opportunity to have a series of macros that generate prototypes to individual stub functions, with a corresponding sequence of macros  in the C++ source generating `extern "C"` stubs.

---

As to the second question: Yes, that works, but the `typedef` is not inside a template. I attempted to put such a typedef inside a class, but it turns out that even class templates are not allowed inside the `extern "C"`. So you can have a function template, but no parameters of dependent type.

Merely defining that function is easy:

```
extern "C" typedef void ftype(int);

template<typename T>
static ftype f; // <- added "static" here

template< typename T >
void f(int q) {}
```

Aha, variadic functions!

```
extern "C" typedef void ftype( int, ... );

template<typename T>
static ftype f;

template< typename T >
static void f( int z, ... ) {
    va_list va;
    va_start( va, z );
    T v = va_arg( va, T );
    va_end( va );

    std::cout << v;
}
```

You don't really need type deduction since it's just a callback, so you can pass this `& f<int>` to the C code, all callbacks having the same type, and it can make the type determination at runtime and pass whatever it wants through the varargs.

Comment: I just used `extern "C" { ... }` instead of `extern "C" ...` because the latter doesn't allow combining it with `static` in a single declaration.

Comment: @Johannes: But you said "So to prevent disabling of mangling…", which I don't understand. Mangling is still disabled there, so the compiler should complain.

Comment: @Potatos, "So to prevent disabling of mangling" refers to the Standard's text saying "function names with external linkage". By putting "static", I give the function name internal linkage, thus preventing that the function's name will get C language linkage. I did experiments which showed that mangling is only affected by the name's linkage, but not by the type's linkage (which is intuitive too, IMO).

Comment: @Johannes: Now I see, thanks. Hmm, it's really a pain that these can only appear at namespace scope…

Comment: The function template you defined later on has a different type, and is thus a different function template then the one you declared in the first declaration (AFAIK only comeau differentiates function types according to their linkage, as it should according to the standard). I.e the following should result in an undefined reference linker error: `extern "C" typedef void f(); f g; void g() { } int main() { f *pg = g; pg(); }`. Note that `f *pg = g;` unambiguously refers to the first, undefined, `g`. Similar things will happen with your two template declarations, I think.

Comment: @Johannes: See this: http://ideone.com/RuE5T - it passes GCC either way, but Comeau only if the `#if 1` part is included.

Comment: Hmm, but even the comeau compiler doesn't agree. It says for this one, that both functions would only differ in the return type. But that's not true because the function type of the one has C linkage, and the one of the other has C++ linkage: `extern "C" typedef int f(); f g; void g() { }`, and that would make the function types differ in addition to differ in the return type. That's weird

Comment: @Johannes: I can paste the text directly from ideone into Comeau and I get a "Compile succeeded" message. Did you start with a blank page and include nothing else?

Comment: @Johannes: N3225 §7.5/5: "A function can be declared without a linkage specification after an explicit linkage specification has been seen; the linkage explicitly specified in the earlier declaration is not affected by such a function declaration."

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I included only `extern "C" typedef int f(); f g; void g() { }`, and it says "error: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone"

Comment: @Johannes: Of course, you've declared one returning `int` and one returning `void`. That's not what I suggest…

Comment: @Potatoswatter that paragraph applies if the second declaration declares the same function as the first. I thought that since the two types are different ("Two function types with different language linkages are distinct types even if they are otherwise identical.") and two function declarations using different types overload each other ("By extension, two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with different types are called overloaded declarations") that they declare different functions.

Comment: But I missed a different paragraph that says "Two function declarations of the same name refer to the same function if they are in the same scope and have equivalent parameter declarations (13.1).". So in fact, you can have two declarations that overload each other, but still declare the same function :)

Comment: @Johannes: I've only been declaring one function here. I don't know where the notion of a function returning `int` came from. Why would there be two functions? The functions differ in template-name; they are not overloads. That's the whole point of this exercise, right?

Comment: But that does not apply to function template declarations. For function template declarations, a different paragraph says "Two distinct function templates may have identical function return types and function parameter lists, even if overload resolution alone cannot distinguish them.". So let's see whether we can trick some more.

Comment: @Potatos, my "Hmm, but even the comeau compiler doesn't agree. " did not refer to your code. It referred to my previous comment.

Comment: Hmm, nope. We cannot even overload function templates based on purely the language linkage of their function type :) The spec says "Two function templates are equivalent if they are declared in the same scope, have the same name, have identical template parameter lists, and have return types and parameter lists that are equivalent using the rules described above to compare expressions involving template parameters.". They just dig through the language linkage and ignore them for declaration matching :)

Comment: @Johannes: I'm thoroughly confused. The fact that the `extern "C" typedef` cannot be templated, and that the callback must be usable from the C language, effectively requires that there be only one callback prototype. It seems to me that I've completely solved your problem; please clarify how this is not the case.

Comment: @Johannes: To reiterate: I am not using any kind of overloading here, nor intending to.

Comment: So I think you have a point. Both your first and your second function template declarations are equivalent and therefor declare the same function template and thus, I think, the rule about "A function can be declared without a linkage specification after an explicit linkage specification has been seen; the linkage explicitly specified in the earlier declaration is not affected by such a function declaration." will apply.

Comment: However since it only talks about "function" and not about "function template", and because it talks about "function that ... has a language linkage" confuses me. What does it mean for a function to have a language linkage? Does it mean its name has linkage, its type has linkage or both have said linkage?

Comment: @Johannes: That part is pretty unclear, since templates are forbidden from having C language linkage at all (14/4). So, `static ftype f` may be noncompliant. But, the beginning of that paragraph mentions names, and it mainly discusses visibility, so it may not be referring to the function type.

Comment: I cannot show you a header. The scenario I explained in my question is purely made up to explain what the question is about.

Comment: @Johannes: Well… my 2¢ is that this kind of problem is better solved by separating the templates from the C with a dispatch mechanism, or by using macros as templates. Especially if this is for a client/employer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason for the restriction, but can't you use a wrapper `extern "C"` function that calls the specific template instantiation you care about?

Answer (score 1):

> ...whether there is an easy work around to achieve my initial goal?

you can approach it from a few angles, depending on how you want to configure and declare them.

four approaches follow, one namespace demonstrates each. 'Type' is probably the simplest for your usage.

```
#include <stdio.h> // favored to reduce exports in later demonstration

#define FUNC_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
// or __func__ or __FUNCTION__ or...

extern "C" {

    /* C prototype */
    typedef void ftype(int a);

    /* the c function all our functions are piped into */
    void call(ftype* a);

    /* helper which serves as the implementation for our functions */
    void print(int a, const char* const func);

    /* C definitions (used in namespace examples below) */
    static void static_float(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    static void static_double(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    void extern_float(int a);
    void extern_float(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    void extern_double(int a);
    void extern_double(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    static void static_function_float(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    static void static_function_double(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

} /* << extern C */

namespace Extern {

    /**
     interface demonstrates C functions as template arguments
    */
    template<ftype Fn>
    struct t_func {
        static ftype* Function() {
            return Fn;
        }
    };

    template<typename T> struct bind;

    template<> struct bind<float> {
        typedef t_func<extern_float> F;
    };

    template<> struct bind<double> {
        typedef t_func<extern_double> F;
    };

    template<typename T>
    void Call(T a) {
        (void) a;
        call(bind<T>::F::Function());
    }

} /* << Extern */

namespace Static {

    /**
     interface demonstrates template types wrapping static C functions
     */
    template<typename T> struct bind;

    template<> struct bind<float> {
        static ftype* F() {
            return static_float;
        }
    };

    template<> struct bind<double> {
        static ftype* F() {
            return static_double;
        }

    };

    template<typename T>
    void Call(T a) {
        (void) a;
        call(bind<T>::F());
    }

} /* << Static */

namespace Function {

    /**
     interface demonstrates template functions wrapping static C functions
     */

    template<typename T> ftype* bind();

    template<> ftype* bind<float> () {
        return static_function_float;
    }

    template<> ftype* bind<double> () {
        return static_function_double;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Call(T a) {
        (void) a;
        call(bind<T> ());
    }

} /* << Function */

namespace Type {

    /**
     interface demonstrates template types implementing static functions.
     although gcc4.2 and clang both compile it, i'm uncertain that this is conforming.
    */

    template<typename T> struct bind {
        static void F(int a);
    };

    template<> void bind<float>::F(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    template<> void bind<double>::F(int a) {
        print(a, FUNC_NAME);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Call(T a) {
        (void) a;
        call(bind<T>::F);
    }

} /* << Type */

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    (void) argc;
    (void) argv;

    const float f(1.0f);
    const double d(5.0);

    Extern::Call(f);
    Extern::Call(d);

    Static::Call(f);
    Static::Call(d);

    Function::Call(f);
    Function::Call(d);

    Type::Call(f);
    Type::Call(d);

    return 0;
}

void call(ftype* a) {
    a(11);
}

void print(int a, const char* const func) {
    printf("%i: %s\n", a, func);
}
```

outputs:

```
11: void extern_float(int)
11: void extern_double(int)
11: void static_float(int)
11: void static_double(int)
11: void static_function_float(int)
11: void static_function_double(int)
11: static void Type::bind<T>::F(int) [with T = float]
11: static void Type::bind<T>::F(int) [with T = double]
```

producing:

```
nm unstripped:
    0000000100000daf s  stub helpers
    0000000100001048 D _NXArgc
    0000000100001050 D _NXArgv
    0000000100000bde T __ZN4Type4bindIdE1FEi
    0000000100000bc0 T __ZN4Type4bindIfE1FEi
    0000000100000d98 s __ZZ12extern_floatE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000c98 s __ZZ12static_floatE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000d80 s __ZZ13extern_doubleE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000cb0 s __ZZ13static_doubleE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000d60 s __ZZ21static_function_floatE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000d38 s __ZZ22static_function_doubleE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000cc8 s __ZZN4Type4bindIdE1FEiE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100000d00 s __ZZN4Type4bindIfE1FEiE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    0000000100001060 D ___progname
    0000000100000000 A __mh_execute_header
    0000000100001058 D _environ
                     U _exit
    0000000100000c00 T _extern_double
    0000000100000b20 T _extern_float
    0000000100000c20 T _main
                     U _printf
    0000000100000b60 t _static_double
    0000000100000b40 t _static_float
    0000000100000ba0 t _static_function_double
    0000000100000b80 t _static_function_float
                     U dyld_stub_binder
    0000000100000ae0 T start


nm stripped:
    0000000100000000 A __mh_execute_header
                     U _exit
                     U _printf
                     U dyld_stub_binder
```

sorry, i'm not poring over standards tonight -- hope that helps. good luck!