# C language linkage typedef & templates

Tags: c++, c, templates, typedef, linkage

I understand that a template cannot appear inside an `extern "C"` block, the reason for which is that the *name* of the instantiated template functions cannot appear once than once using an unmangled name.

However, in the code below, the name of the function *is* being mangled (so there should be no problem because each instantiation will have a unique name) but still has function type with C language linkage. My question is whether the code below is well formed:

```
extern "C" using fn_type = void();

template<typename T>
fn_type foo;

int main()
{
    fn_type* const p = foo<int>;
    p();
}
```

Edit: it is hard to test if this is conforming just by running it through a compiler because GCC, Clang and MSVC don't distinguish between C++ and C function pointer types.

Comment: so, you want to compile c++ code with c compiler? Or what?

Comment: @BЈовић I want to pass some functions to a C function which obviously expects `extern "C"` function pointers.

Comment: @Angew the `extern "C"` block conflates the *name* and the *type*. Template functions cannot be declared in an `extern "C"` block because the name of every instantion would be the same. However, in `template<typename T> fn_type foo;` the name *is* being mangled (so there should be no problem because each instantiation will have a unique name) but the type should still have C language linkage. There's a good answer on this site explaining the difference between how language linkage affects names and types independantly but I'm struggling to find it.

Comment: @Angew I made a typo. Read the comment again please :P

Comment: [I believe I found the question/answer I was referring to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763919/what-does-mean-for-a-name-or-type-to-have-a-certain-language-linkage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the standard does not seem 100% clear on this. The only relevant part which mentions templates and linkage is C++11, [temp]§4:

> A template name has linkage (3.5). A non-member function template can have internal linkage; any other template name shall have external linkage. Specializations (explicit or implicit) of a template that has internal linkage are distinct from all specializations in other translation units. **A template, a template explicit specialization (14.7.3), and a class template partial specialization shall not have C linkage.** Use of a linkage specification other than C or C++ with any of these constructs is conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics. *[...]*

(Emphasis mine)

The paragraph starts with template *names* having linkage. Then it says "funciton *template* `(not`*`name`*`)` can have internal linkage; any other template *name* shall have external linkage."

To me, this seems to imply referring to the linkage of a template refers to the linkage of the template's *name.* If that interpretation is correct, then your example is well-formed, as the bolded part would apply to template *names* as well. Then nothing prevents function template *types* from having C linkage.

That's how I would interpret the standard.